# Xamarin.Forms validate textfields in a webview to show iOS native popup

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have done some research online, but have found nothing that ***directly*** answers my question here. Is there a way to validate a WebView form via Xamarin.Forms?

In my exact scenario, I would like to assure that if there is a textfield that is left empty within the WebView then I will display a native iOS alert (DisplayAlert).

My asynchronous Task looks somewhat like below:

```
private async Task<string> FormValidation ()
    {
        WebView wv = new WebView();

       string elementID = "mobileShipFromCsp1";
       string x = await wv.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('{elementID}').value;");
        Console.WriteLine("This is x: " + x);

        if(x == "")
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "This should work", "Ok");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("This is x: " + x);
        return x;

    }
```

But there is no alert showing at the press of submit.

I cannot bind the submit button to this Task, seeing that there is no button in the xaml (because we are calling a webview).

This is my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <views:WebViewContainerBaseView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout> 
   <webviews:WebviewContainer x:Name="shippingView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  

    BackgroundColor="white"/>
    </StackLayout> 

      </ContentPage.Content> 
      </views:WebViewContainerBaseView>
```

Comment: Look at the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows), I assume you would need to handle the WebView's navigating or navigated property. This other link might also be helpful (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

Comment: Although i also notice in your code you instantiate a new WebView object, does it actually have the appropriate html for your JS code to even target it correctly?

Comment: Great question. That is what I was wondering as well. In the XAML the name of the Webview is 'shippingView'. But when I try and type shippingView.EncapsulateJavaScriptAsync, it says EncapsulateAsyncy is not found in this context. I am not sure, but great point.

Comment: shippingView I assume is of type webview? If it is, and you're still having issues getting its Evaluate  function you might have to make those custom renderers as those links describe

Comment: The new webview you created in the task is not the one(webviews:WebviewContainer) you use in your xaml.